# Finding locus of centre of circle

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems, locus

> The locus of the center of the circles such that the point $(2,3)$ is midpoint of the chord $5x +2y =16$ is
>
> (A) $2x-5y+11=0$
>
> (B) $2x+5y-11=0$
>
> (C) $2x+5y+11=0$
>
> (D) None of these

**I do not want solution, the real question is given below**

**This is how I solved it:**

Let, the center be **(h,k)**,now the distance between (2,3) and (h,k) equals to distance of (h,k) from line  $5x +2y =16$, thus
$$(h-2)^2+(k-3)^2 = \frac{(5(h)+2(k)-16)^2}{5^2+2^2}$$ You can see I have already squared both sides. Now this clearly gives a 2 degree equation not a linear one as given in options.

But when I saw solution of this question, its given that $$(\frac{-5}{2})(\frac{k-3}{h-2})=-1$$Now this gives option A, .i.e. a linear locus, So you can see that I have a 2 degree locus, but the book has 1 degree, **how can both be correct at the same time**, is any one of the solutions wrong, is so explain, and if both are correct, then explain why there are 2 different locus for same conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of the circle is on the perpendicular $(p)$ in $(2,3)$ on the line with equation $5x+2y=16$, having slope $m=-\frac 52$, so $(p)$ has slope $m'=-\frac 1m=\frac 25$, so it has an equation of the shape $5y-2x=?$, and because $(2,3)$ satisfies, the equation is
$$
5y-2x=11\ .
$$
We get the solution (A).

---

Now consider also the equation of degree two...
$$
(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2 = \frac{(5x+2y-16)^2}{5^2+2^2}\ .
$$
We can equivalently rewrite it successively:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(5^2+2^2)((x-2)^2+(y-3)^2) &= (5x+2y-16)^2\ ,\\
(5^2+2^2)((x-2)^2+(y-3)^2) &= (\ 5(x-2)+2(y-3)\ )^2\ ,\\
5^2(x-2)^2+5^2(y-3)^2+2^2(x-2)^2+2^2(y-3)^2 &= 5^2(x-2)^2+2\cdot5(x-2)\cdot 2(y-3)+2^2(y-3)^2\ ,\\
5^2(y-3)^2+2^2(x-2)^2 &= 2\cdot5(x-2)\cdot 2(y-3)\ ,\\
(\ 5(y-3)-2(x-2)\ )^2 &=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is also (A), over a field.

Comment: I did not asked that, I already have the solution you gave, I asked **Why** there are two different locus, read full question.

Comment: @Usercomingsoon There aren’t two loci. Your second-degree equation is that of a double line.

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic equation appears when you square the expressions.

Geometrically, a given distance to the point gives a circle and the same distance to the line gives two lines, on both sides, so that for a given common distance there are two solutions. In fact, your equation is a perfect square, representing twice the same line.

We see this by moving the point to the origin and writing

$$h^2+k^2=\frac{(ah+bk)^2}{a^2+b^2}.$$

It is easy to check that this is also

$$\frac{(bh-ak)^2}{a^2+b^2}=0.$$

---

You could have solved using the algebraic distance to the line (i.e. positive on one side, negative on the other), and process

$$\sqrt{h^2+k^2}=\frac{ah+bk}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},$$

(without an absolute value).

---

At the same time this gives the solution, as the linear coefficients must be proportional to $(b,-a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion that since the equations are of differing degree there are two different loci is incorrect. What you have are two equations for the *same* set of points. The second-degree equation that you derived simplifies to $$\frac1{29}(5k-2h-11)^2 = 0.$$ The given solution, on the other hand, simplifies to $\frac12(5k-2h-11)=0$. It should be obvious that the graphs of the two equations are identical.